# Legendre's Theorem for Non-Pairwise Coprime Coefficients?

Tags: number-theory, conic-sections, quadratic-forms

I want to solve the problem of existence of rational points on conic sections by using the theorem of Legendre (1785):

> Fix squarefree and pairwise-coprime integers $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, not all of the same sign. Then there exist rational numbers $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying $ax^2+by^2+c=0$ if and only if ($-ba$ is square mod $c$), ($-ac$ is square mod $b$) and ($-bc$ is square mod $a$).

So far I have been able to reduce the problem to the case of $ax^2+by^2+c=0$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ are squarefree integers, not all of the same sign, such that $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b,c)=1$.

**Question:** Can the case $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b,c)=1$ be reduced to the Legendre case $$\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=\mathrm{gcd}(a,c)=\mathrm{gcd}(b,c)=1$$ or is there some idea missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose two of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are divisible by some $d$,
say $b=b'd$, $c=c'd$. Then $ax^2+by^2+c=ax^2+b'dy^2+c'd=0$
is soluble iff $(a/d)x^2+b'y^2+c'=0$ is soluble iff $adx^2+b'y^2+c'=0$ is soluble. Note $d>1$ means that $|(ad)b'c'|<|abc|$.

Comment: Thanks. It was the $|(ad)b'c'|<|abc|$ step that I was missing. I wasn't expecting that the problem would require induction.